# How to hide / show div(s) with differing tag values based on multiple checkbox filters

Tags: html, typescript

I have a page that displays multiple notices with different component tags, and I'd like to show / hide notice elements with a checkbox selection corresponding to the tag name (ih / cli / whatever else that might be needed in the future). There can also be multiple tags associated with one notice.

So based on the layout below, if I select the helper checkbox filter, 3 of the 4 notices should appear, if the cli filter is selected, 2/4 should appear, etc.

```html
<div class="notices-container">
  <div class="notices-filter">
    <div class="notices-filter-header">Filter By Tag</div>
    <div class="notices-filter-body">
      <form class="grid-inline">
        <div class="custom-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="ih" checked>
          <label class="custom-control-label">Helper</label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="cli" checked>
          <label class="custom-control-label">CLI</label>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="notices" id="notices">
    <h2 class="notices-header">Release Notes</h2>

    <div class="notice">
      <div class="notice-tags">
        <div class="notice-tag notice-tag-cli" id="cli"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="notice">
      <div class="notice-tags">
        <div class="notice-tag notice-tag-ih" id="ih"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="notice">
      <div class="notice-tags">
        <div class="notice-tag notice-tag-cli" id="cli"></div>
        <div class="notice-tag notice-tag-ih" id="ih"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="notice">
      <div class="notice-tags">
        <div class="notice-tag notice-tag-ih" id="ih"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Typescript code:

```js
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']")

checkboxes.forEach((box) => {
    box.addEventListener('click', function () {
        // casting this because I didn't have access to the checked field otherwise
        filter(<HTMLInputElement>box.name, <HTMLInputElement>box.checked)
    })
})

function filter(filterId, isChecked) {
    let componentTags = document.getElementsByClassName('notice-tag')

    for (var tag = 0; tag < componentTags.length; tag++) {
        if (isChecked && componentTags[tag].id === "ih") {
            componentTags[tag].parentElement.parentElement.style.display = "block"
        } else if (isChecked && componentTags[tag].id === "cli") {
            componentTags[tag].parentElement.parentElement.style.display = "block"
        } else {
            componentTags[tag].parentElement.parentElement.style.display = "none"
        }
    }
}
```

(Not posting the css because it's irrelevant to the question)

The above code works to show / hide all the elements if either of the checkboxes are toggled, but fails to filter individual notices. Instead of the display style being set on the individual notice element, the css is modified for all of them. Is there a way to set the style on specific notices without setting the rule for all of them?

I tried looking at https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_elements.asp for insight on filtering elements but it's quite hard to understand and recreating it didn't seem to work.

I'm very new (just started) to front-end so would really appreciate any ideas or alternate approaches!

---

```js
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']")

checkboxes.forEach((box) => {
  box.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // casting this because I didn't have access to the checked field otherwise
    filter(box.name, box.checked)
  })
})

function filter(filterId, isChecked) {
  let componentTags = document.getElementsByClassName('notice-tag')

  for (var tag = 0; tag < componentTags.length; tag++) {
    if (isChecked && componentTags[tag].id === "ih") {
      componentTags[tag].parentElement.parentElement.style.display = "block"
    } else if (isChecked && componentTags[tag].id === "cli") {
      componentTags[tag].parentElement.parentElement.style.display = "block"
    } else {
      componentTags[tag].parentElement.parentElement.style.display = "none"
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="notices-container">
  <div class="notices-filter">
    <div class="notices-filter-header">Filter By Tag</div>
    <div class="notices-filter-body">
      <form class="grid-inline">
        <div class="custom-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="ih" checked>
          <label class="custom-control-label">Helper</label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="cli" checked>
          <label class="custom-control-label">CLI</label>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="notices" id="notices">
    <h2 class="notices-header">Release Notes</h2>

    <div class="notice">
      <div class="notice-tags">
        <div class="notice-tag notice-tag-cli" id="cli"></div>
      </div>
      Notice 1 (CLI)
    </div>
    <div class="notice">
      <div class="notice-tags">
        <div class="notice-tag notice-tag-ih" id="ih"></div>
      </div>
      Notice 2 (IH)
    </div>
    <div class="notice">
      <div class="notice-tags">
        <div class="notice-tag notice-tag-cli" id="cli"></div>
        <div class="notice-tag notice-tag-ih" id="ih"></div>
      </div>
      Notice 3 (CLI/IH)
    </div>
    <div class="notice">
      <div class="notice-tags">
        <div class="notice-tag notice-tag-ih" id="ih"></div>
      </div>
      Notice 4 (IH)
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the bottom is a snippet that works the way you describe. I will walk through the changes that were made:

---

First, in order for this system to work at all, your `filter` function needs to be aware of the status of *both* checkboxes, since if it only knows one, it might incorrectly hide an element, even if its other tag checkbox is still checked.

In order to help with that, create a function that lets you look at the status of those checkboxes at any time. Eg, something like:

```
function getCheckboxStatus() {
    const statuses = {};
    checkboxes.forEach(box => statuses[box.name] = box.checked);
    return statuses;
}
```

This just returns an object with the tag name as the key, and true/false as the value, indicating if that tag's checkbox is checked or not.

---

Second, you need to show the element if *any* of it's tags are checked, and since you can have multiple tags per notice, it will be much easier to iterate through the notice elements (parents) and check each one's children, rather than iterating through the tags (children) and modifying the parent.

For that, you just need to change the query selector to look for the parent elements instead, eg:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('notice-tags')
```

Noting that it checks for `notice-tags` now instead of `notice-tag`.

---

Finally, to simplify the logic of checking if any of the present tags are checked, I created a small helper function to return the list of tags that are on the given notice:

```
function tagsForNotice(notice) {
    return [...notice.children].map(tag => tag.id)
}
```

This just returns any array with the tag names, so if you give it the third notice, for example, it would return `["ih", "cli"]`.

---

Putting all that together, we seem to get the behavior you wanted:

```js
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']")

checkboxes.forEach((box) => {
  box.addEventListener('click', function() {
    filter()
  })
});

// Helper function, since you need to know the checked status of ALL checkboxes to properly filter.
function getCheckboxStatus() {
  const statuses = {};
  checkboxes.forEach(box => statuses[box.name] = box.checked);
  return statuses;
}

// Another helper function, gives a list of tags when given the parent component.
function tagsForNotice(notice) {
  return [...notice.children].map(tag => tag.id)
}

function filter() {
  // Will need to know the status of BOTH checkboxes:
  let checkedStatus = getCheckboxStatus();
  // console.log("Current checkbox status:", checkedStatus);

  // Get the parent elements instead, then check children.
  let noticeComponents = document.getElementsByClassName('notice-tags')

  // For each parent, if ANY of it's child tags are marked checked, show it.
  // Otherwise hide it.
  for (let noticeIndex = 0; noticeIndex < noticeComponents.length; noticeIndex++) {
    // Get children tags:
    let tags = tagsForNotice(noticeComponents[noticeIndex]);
    
    // Are ANY of those checked?
    let any_checked = tags.some(tag => checkedStatus[tag]);
    
    // If so, show, otherwise hide.
    if (any_checked) {
      noticeComponents[noticeIndex].parentElement.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      noticeComponents[noticeIndex].parentElement.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="notices-container">
  <div class="notices-filter">
    <div class="notices-filter-header">Filter By Tag</div>
    <div class="notices-filter-body">
      <form class="grid-inline">
        <div class="custom-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="ih" checked>
          <label class="custom-control-label">Helper</label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="cli" checked>
          <label class="custom-control-label">CLI</label>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="notices" id="notices">
    <h2 class="notices-header">Release Notes</h2>

    <div class="notice">
      <div class="notice-tags">
        <div class="notice-tag notice-tag-cli" id="cli"></div>
      </div>
      Notice 1 (CLI)
    </div>
    <div class="notice">
      <div class="notice-tags">
        <div class="notice-tag notice-tag-ih" id="ih"></div>
      </div>
      Notice 2 (IH)
    </div>
    <div class="notice">
      <div class="notice-tags">
        <div class="notice-tag notice-tag-cli" id="cli"></div>
        <div class="notice-tag notice-tag-ih" id="ih"></div>
      </div>
      Notice 3 (CLI/IH)
    </div>
    <div class="notice">
      <div class="notice-tags">
        <div class="notice-tag notice-tag-ih" id="ih"></div>
      </div>
      Notice 4 (IH)
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As a side note: Avoid having multiple html elements with the same `id` property. The `id` is supposed to uniquely identify a _single_ element. But I have not changed it here in order to keep as much similarity to your original code as possible.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks!